# Issue when using DOMREADY of mootools in different html pages

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mootools

I am facing an issue with DOMREADY while using different id from different pages.
For Example

JS

```
var clickFunction = function(){
//put whatever you want to happen in here
alert('this element now recognizes the click event');
}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('id_name').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('id_2').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
});
```

HTML
Case1

```
<body>    
<div id="id_name"> <a onclick="javascript:void(0);">link1</a></div>
<div id="id_2"> <a onclick="javascript:void(0);">link2</a></div> 
</body>
```

It works fine when click on link2

Case2

```
<body>   
<div id="id_name"> <a onclick="javascript:void(0);">link1</a>     </div> 
</body>
```

It works fine When click on link1

Case3

```
<body>   
<div id="id_2"> <a onclick="javascript:void(0);">link2</a>     </div> 
</body>
```

It doesn't work

Comment: *Doesn't work* as in the event is never fired?

Comment: What `onclick="javascript:void(0);"` are there for?

Answer (score 1):

because you don't actually protect yourself against an exception.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('id_name').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('id_2').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
});
```

first of all, you don't need 2 domready functions. they stack up but you can use one.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('id_name').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
    $('id_2').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
});
```

however, what you do still is wrong as it's coupled to DOM without any checks.

you ASSUME `$('id_name')` will return an object and you immediately call the .addEvent method on it. it works for case 1 as that is the first line evaluated at runtime.

in your second file, if won't get to the id_2 add event because id1 will try to call addEvent on a non-element (it's not in the dom), so null. this causes an exception and your javascript never finishes.

you have 3 ways of protecting yourself.

### 1. use an elements collection.

```
document.getElements('#id_2,#id_name').addEvent('click', clickFunction);
```

this will try to get both, but it will be happy with either or none as it iterates through the result. if the selector returns 0 elements, it won't loop at all

### 2. pass a reference to a var and see if its truthy or null

```
var id_name = document.id('id_name');
if (id_name) {
    id_name.addEvent('click', clickFunction);
}

// or write as
id_name && id_name.addEvent();
```

### 3. delegate the events to a parent element.

benefit is, only 1 event binding can work with n-number of elements which may come later via ajax or via a dynamic element constructor.

eg.

```
$('menu').addEvent('click:relay(#id_name,#id_2)', function(event, element){
    // do something.
});
```